# Google Analytics set up, beacon sent, Analytics shows nothing

Tags: google-analytics

I installed Google Analitycs (UA) like I always do (ctrl-c - ctrl-v tracking code from Analytics page to wordpress installation).

Everything seems to be ok, but Google Analytics shows nothing. It always started tracking site seconds after pasting code on website (real-time preview). It shows nothing now.

- There are no errors in scripts.
- Page has is http
- I have no browser extensions like Disconnect or AdBlock enabled.
- I opened my page from different network from mobile phone.
- I installed GA Debug, it shows correct data and it shows what beacon was sent.
- I connected GWT with no problems (html file verification)
- I tested tracking on fresh Wordpress installation on same server
- I tested it on simple html page on same server

It looks the same every time. We have new server - LAMP with PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4.

I have no ideas left. What else can I check? Is it possible that server's configuration causes this problem?

Comment: Can you share your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. I just left it as it was.

Apparently Google needed some time to start tracking. Real time preview always worked immediately after pasting tracking code. This time it took couple of hours.

Update: I tested my theory once again: new property = you have to wait some time (hours, not minutes) to see first tracking results **including real time.**

Comment: When you say "including real time" does that mean it won't show up straight away on the Realtime report? I know I sound thick but just clarifying.

Comment: @KenSharp: it happens that correctly installed Analytics shows absolutely **nothing** when the property is just created, also Realtime report shows 0 users even there are users. 
From my experience time may vary from "it works straight away" to "couple of hours".

Answer (score 0):

```
What else can I check?
```

Look at the developer tools and make sure the script is actually loading.  On Chrome and Firefox there is a network tab that will allow you to see what GET requests the browser is making to load your site.

```
Is it possible that servers configuration causes this problem?
```

I can't really think of any likely scenario that would cause this to happen from a server perspective.  You are sending your client side code to the browser to execute.  If you haven't give the client valid code, you won't get a valid result.

EDIT: Also, make sure that you've correctly entered your analytics account ID in the script and configured it properly inside analytics.

Comment: Network tab: analytics.js: 200 OK. It's also present under resources tab in scripts.
Account ID is correct, I just copied the code that Google generated. URL is correct and set to http. I deleted property and created it again. Same result.

Comment: I've seen it take up to 24 hours before I started seeing any data.  Have you tried looking at the real time data?

Comment: I'm talking about real time data. It fixed itself right now (or someone hacked my site and set it up correctly :) ). I did nothing, maybe Google needed some time to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Today is not included by default in the report (today is Feb 23).

[image]

Also check the 'Real time' report.

[image]